# Pick a winner of scores from a row in Excel with multiple winners

Tags: vba, excel

I have a set of data as per the below, want want to automatically find the winner.

```
A B C D E 
1 2 3 4 5
```

I have used the `INDEX` function:

```
INDEX($A$1:$E$1,1,MATCH(LARGE($A$2:$E$2,1),$A$2:$E$2,0))
```

This does indeed tell me that the winner is E.

However, say the next dataset suggests that A and E have the same score:

```
A B C D E 
5 2 3 4 5
```

Using the above formula, I am unable to get both A and E as winners...

Is it possible to nest an IF function and concact, such that in my winners column it could say: 
A, E?

Comment: The `INDEX` formula can only return one result, I think you cannot resolve this without using VBA. Therefore start on your own writing a code and if you get stuck come back with that code and a question related to it.

Comment: Have tried to avoid the time on vba :( best get started ay ...

Comment: @pablo144 - edited a one liner array formula solving your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Improvised array formula**

What about an array formula copied down (starting e.g. in cell F2):

`=SUM(LARGE(IF(A2:E2=MAX(A2:E2),COLUMN(A2:E2),0),COLUMN(A2:E2))*10^(COLUMN(A2:E2)-1)`

(Take care of the curly brackets {} indicating correct Input of an array formula!)

The result returns e.g. `15`, i.e. digit one shows the 1st and the next digit the 5th column as winning based on your example data `5 2 3 4 5` (in columns A:E).

If there occur e.g. `1 5 5 4 5` in columns A:E the result would be ►  `235` revealing the 2nd, 3rd and 5th column as winning.

*Note: restricted to 10 single digits (10 columns) as it uses the decimal number system in this example (could be modified).

**Edit 1 - display a comma separated string with column letters**

It's not of utmost elegance to use repeated `SUBSTITUTE` functions, but it does the job for this restricted number of columns:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUM(LARGE(IF(A2:E2=MAX(A2:E2),COLUMN(A2:E2),0),COLUMN(A2:E2))*10^(COLUMN(A2:E2)-1)),1,"A,"),2,"B,"),3,"C,"),4,"D,"),5,"E,")&"#",",#","")
```

The occurance of e.g. `1 5 5 4 5` in columns `A:E`  would result here in ►  `B,C,E` displaying the winning column letters as comma separated string.

**Edit 2 - slim alternative using hexadecimal number system (without commas)**

This approach uses the fact that the hexadecimal system codes numbers > 9 with alphanum characters A to F and simply adds 9 to the found column values:

```
=DEC2HEX(SUM(LARGE(IF(A2:E2=MAX(A2:E2),COLUMN(A2:E2)+9,0),COLUMN(A2:E2))*16^(COLUMN(A2:E2)-1)))
```

The occurance of e.g. `1 5 5 4 5` in columns `A:E`  would result here in ► `BCE` via a tricky use of *hexadecimal* number conversion.

Enjoy it :-)

Comment: This looks promising ... but would need a way for it to show AE vs 15, and finding a way to concatenating a comma in there would be ideal :)

Comment: Is there not a way to append a comma or something to the output? 235 could easily be misinterpreted as several numbers once the number of rows is large

Comment: As it's no beauty contest you can use repeated `SUBSTITUTE` functions to transforme the `SUM` result into a comma separated string: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUM(LARGE(IF(A2:E2=MAX(A2:E2),COLUMN(A2:E2),0),COLUMN(A2:E2))*10^(COLUMN(A2:E2)-1)),1,"A,"),2,"B,"),3,"C,"),4,"D,"),5,"E,")&"#",",#","")
`

Comment: @T.M. Thanks very much. I am trying to wrap my head around this - say I add an extra column at the start which is a list of names (column A), so now want to do the same, but from B2:F2. It doesn't seem to like this, and I can't figure out why

Comment: @pablo144 - You are welcome. - As to your additional question: If you have an inserted column A you can use `=SUM(LARGE(IF(B2:F2=MAX(B2:F2),COLUMN($A2:$E2),0),COLUMN($A2:$E2))*10^(COLUMN($A2:$E2)-1))` calculating with same numbering system (same result) but a changed range `B:F` to check for `MAX`. Do the same with the other formulae. If you want to shift the column titles, too (A->B, B->C etc.) you would have to substitute 1 with B, 2 with C etc. in Edit 1 formula and simply add 10 instead of 9 in the Edit 2 formula. 
`

Answer (score 3):

The easiest idea that comes to my mind is:

Pick some empty cell, for example `G1` and paste there following formula:

```
=MAX(A1:E1)
```

Then apply [**conditional formatting**](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f) to the range: color cell if it equals `G1` (instead of `G1` you could enter formula itself `=MAX(A1:E1)`, but for me it gave unexpected results).

This way, all winners will be highlighted right after value change.

**UPDATE**

You might use conditional formatting slightly different:

[image]

Sorry, my Excel is in Polish, but you should be able to follow:

1. Click conditional formatting
2. Expand greatest / smallest rules (or something similair)
3. Click "10 first elements" or something like that
4. In pop-up window (number two on the screen) change from 10 to 1.

Now you have formatting that you want. Now you need to copy and paste special this formatting for every row separately.

**SECOND UPDATE**

To easily apply it to all rows, you could do the following:

Record a macro, after starting recording, select the row A1:E1, apply conditional formatting described earlier, stop recording and open the code for the macro, it should be like this:

```
Sub Makro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:E1").Select
    Range("E1").Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.AddTop10
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1)
        .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
        .Rank = 1
        .Percent = False
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Font
        .Color = -16383844
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 13551615
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End Sub
```

Now, we will modify it in such way, so it applies desired conditional formatting to all rows automatically:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ApplyConditionalFormatting()
    Dim r As Range, lastRow As Long, i As Long
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastRow

        Set r = Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 5))

        r.FormatConditions.AddTop10
        r.FormatConditions(r.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With r.FormatConditions(1)
            .TopBottom = xlTop10Top
            .Rank = 1
            .Percent = False
        End With
        With r.FormatConditions(1).Font
            .Color = -16383844
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        With r.FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 13551615
            .TintAndShade = 0
        End With
        r.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False

    Next
End Sub
```

I simply made `For` loop and put all recorded code into that loop, so it applies the macro to all rows :)

Comment: What about `"=A2 = MAX($A$2:$E$2)"` applied for range $A$1:$E$2  :-) +1

Comment: Agree that would work for one row only, but my dataset is compromised over 100 rows so that won't be suitable :(

Comment: @pablo144 Do you want winner row-wise, or one winner for whole table?

Comment: use `=A2=MAX(2:2)` as conditional formatting rule for row 2 and copy format down

Comment: @Peh as I mentioned, doing this way, works unexpectedly for me.

Comment: @T.M. the issue with your formula was that the row is fixed by `$` too. So you can fix the column to limit it to column A to E but you need to at least keep the row dynamic like `=A2 = MAX($A2:$E2)` to make it work for more than row number 2.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn I didn't have any issues with the formula `=A2=MAX(2:2)` or `=A2=MAX($A2:$E2)` as conditional formatting rule directly. Eg if data is in range A2:E100 then just select that range and add a condition with one of these formulas worked perfectly for me.

Comment: @PEH - danke/thanks for the helpful hint, was assuming the data range to be limited to one row :-)

Comment: Thanks for you help ... I am convert to this if I can't find a solution to getting it in a separate column... the reason I am persistent in getting it in that format is I already have some conditional formatting on my table (using the colour scales - from high to low). My dataset is just v large and noisy, so would be nice to highlight the winner in its own column clearly